# 'root'@'localhost' access denied, no password used

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have downloaded WAMPServer to learn PHP and MySQL. While invoking MySQL console, when I press Enter at the password prompt, I get the following error:

```
error 1045 (28000) access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I get the same error if I try to start mysql from the command line. Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Please note that I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow regarding this error but majority of those questions had (using password: YES).

Comment: How did you configure WAMP? If you have a root password you should enter that.

Comment: i did the normal installation without any manual configuration. The online documentation mentions that default password should be empty. No idea why its not working for me.

Comment: What is the command you are using to start `mysql` from the command line?

Comment: mysql -u root and mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 0):

Default password is `''` (empty) apparently.

To see what your password might be set to try this: go to `wamp installation path\apps\`, for example `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin2.10.1`

In this path you can find the file named `config.inc.php`.

Open that file with any text editor and search for:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']
```

the password should be stored here.

Comment: I don't see this field defined: Below is the relevant config:           /* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Comment: i just reinstalled and still see the same problem

Comment: I guess the issue is that my config.inc.php does not have $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, password should be empty, so left click on the icon in the tray area and select **MySQL > MySQL console**. Password should be empty so hit ENTER without typing anything. You can set a new password there with the following commands:

`use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root';
flush privileges;
\q`

Alternatively, if not... as you are saying it is a clean installation, if i were you, i would delete the subdirectory "bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data" and do a reinstall, but bare in mind this has to be a fresh installation, otherwise it would **DELETE ALL YOUR DATABASES** or in other words **ALL MYSQL DATA**.

Answer (score 0):

Open  Command Prompt and type this command:

```
mysqladmin -u root  password "newpassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the false alarm. Basically I had a stale installation of mySQL on my machine that was interfering with WAMP installation. I removed that older installation, re-installed wamp server and had no problems invoking mysql console or phpmyadmin. Apologize again for this issue and thanks to everyone who provided their inputs.

Answer (score 0):

flush out the privilages of the mysql user and try again ,it will work

refer this to grants privilage

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html